# Gotomeeting API call for attendees of ongoing meeting

Tags: logmein

In gotomeeting API reference, https://goto-developer.logmeininc.com/content/gotomeeting-api-reference there is only GET /meetings/{meetingId}/attendees which returns the attendees list of historical meeting. Is there any way I can get the attendees list of ongoing meeting? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You extract data from GoToMeeting using API,

I used python to extract the information.

First you need to setup your account in gotomeeting developer, then you will get clientId and secret key. Store those information.

And get the access token and refresh token.

For extracting information of attendees, you can look for the below code

```
with open(refresh_tokens.json','r') as f:
    myJson = json.load(f)
    access_token = myJson['access_token']


headers = {
'Authorization': 'Bearer '+access_token
}

urlMeeting = 'https://api.getgo.com/G2M/rest/meetings/{}/attendees'
urlMeeting = urlMeeting.format(meetingId)


response = requests.request("GET" , url=urlMeeting , headers=headers)

jsonResponse = json.loads(response.text)
```

I think this will solve your problem.